# How to disable shutdown option at the login screen?

Tags: windows-8.1, group-policy

I was able to disable the shutdown option in the start screen using Group Policy but how do I disable the shutdown button at the login screen? I'm using Windows 8.1 Update 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Group Policy, go to Computer Configuration -> Policies -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Local Policies -> Security Options

There is a setting labeled "Shutdown: Allow system to be shut down without having to log on"  Set that to "Disabled"

That way, no one can shut it down unless they log on first, but by then they're covered by the group policy that removes the shut down option.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to disable the shutdown button at the login screen using the registry.

1. Launch the registry editor
2. Locate the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`
3. Set change the value of `shutdownwithoutlogon` from `1` to **`0`**.

Comment: ...All this does is make the register change manually the group policy that handles this behavior should be used instead to apply it across all applicible machines.

Comment: I agree. I only found the registry way of doing it when searching.